# Does lombok '@Slf4j' slows down object initialization?

Tags: performance, lombok

I am using couple of custom libraries that we built, which is heavily using lombok annotations, especially, `@Slf4j`. As I log the time takes for the time taken for the creation of each beans, I see the classes with `@Slf4j` annotations is taking too much of time(like 30s or so) to create.

Mine is a average sized project with around 90 jar dependencies. Is my observation that `@Slf4j` slowing down the initialization makes sense? If so, what is the fix?

Answer (score 2):

`@Slf4j` is transformed during compilation into this code fragment:

```java
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

The annotation itself is then removed from the class file (i.e., not present at runtime). Thus, the performance issue you experience may be due to the performance of `LoggerFactory.getLogger()`, whose performance depends on the logging backend in use (e.g., logback or log4j).

There will be no difference in performance whether you write that line manually or use lombok.